# How far back does Github track commits?

Tags: github, version-control

I'm sure this information is out there somewhere, but I've been searching  for quite awhile and haven't come up with anything. My question is, how far back does Github track your commits? Like if I screwed up my code and wanted to revert back to how I had it many commits ago, how far back would the history go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

History goes back to when you started your project ***in Git***. Doesn't matter when it was added to Github, Github just stores the repo. For example, [here's one of my projects which predates Github by half a year](https://github.com/schwern/Gravatar-URL/commits/master?after=b14646d69d2ba37d1909f2c349c92ef9d4f8d57c+69). Here's [a commit from 2001](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commit/de84faa459bf31e2a32b5bb9b43c9170875365d2) before Git even existed, that repository has been migrated through several version control systems.

Instead, Github limits the *size* of the repository. There's [a soft limit of 1 GB per repository](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/), meaning Github will request you reduce the repository size rather than simply deny it, and a hard limit of 100 MB per file. Note that's the total size of the repository, not the size of the current checkout.

If you have to store very large files, use [git-lfs (Large File Storage)](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/).

As a side note, because of the way Git works, you cannot drop or alter old commits without altering every commit after it. Github can't quietly truncate your history even if it wanted to.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Am I correct in thinking that every time you make a change and then commit, the size of the repository will grow because it then has to keep the history of the change? Like, if I deleted a chunk of code and added in a new chunk the size of the one deleted, would it grow the size of that chunk since it now has history of both those chunks? Or is the repository size simply how big the files currently are?

Comment: @HenryBergin Yes, every commit will grow the size of the repository, but usually by much less than the size of the diff. Git is ***extremely*** good with its storage space. For example, the entire history of Ruby, 41140 commits going back to 1998, is just 177 megs (the checked out files are 60 megs). You should never have to worry about the 1 gig limit. The exception is binary files like images, video, audio, spreadsheets, Word docs, encrypted, and compressed files. Git has trouble getting diffs and compressing them, so they can rapidly balloon your repository size. Then you use git-lfs.

Comment: @HenryBergin And unlike other version control systems, branches are basically free. Creating a branch costs nothing, it's just a label pointing at the current commit. Committing to a branch costs the same as any other commit. You can see the "branch heads" in `.git/refs/heads/` or `.git/packed-refs`.